# Git push new branch with same files, uploads all files again

Tags: git, push

Given following scenario.

1. Create new branch
2. Commit a 10MB file
3. Git push (uploads the 10MB file)
4. Create a new branch (orphan)
5. Commit the same 10mb file (no changes made, same object sha hash)
6. Git push uploads the 10MB file AGAIN

My expectations are, that the already uploaded files won't be uploaded again using `git push`. But what actual happens is that when a new branch is made all files (even when thousands of smaller source files, instead of one 10MB file) will be uploaded again and again.

My question: How can I make it that Git detects that the 10mb file is already uploaded? Do you know a workaround/fix to make Git detecting already existing objects on the server when pushing commits?
Git detects files by its sha, so it should be able to detect that some files in the tree of the commit are already present on the server.

Possible use-case: I have two completely different branches, but some common files are shared within those two. When I push one branch, I don't want to upload the common files again when I push the second branch.

Actual use-case: I do a lot of machine learning experiments using Python scripts and some smaller datasets (1MB - 10MB). Every time I start an experiment, I add all necessary experiment files to a new Git tree, and use that tree in a new commit without branching. That commits hangs completely free in the air and gets then referenced with a new Git reference (e.g. refs/jobs/my-experiment-name). When I now have two experiments with almost the same files (and thus two references), Git pushes all objects again when I push those references. I have low bandwidth and this really slows down my work.

```
$ mkdir git-test && cd git-test
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username/projectname.git

# create dummy 10MB file
$ head -c 10000000 /dev/urandom > dummy

$ git add dummy
$ git commit -m 'init'

# first push, uploads everything - makes sense
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 9.54 MiB | 1.13 MiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

# create new empty branch, not based from master
$ git checkout --orphan branch2

# add same files again
$ git add dummy
$ git commit -m 'init on branch2'

# this uploads now again the dummy file (10MB), although the server
# has that object alread
$ git push origin branch3
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 9.54 MiB | 838.00 KiB/s, done.
```

On the technical side we have:

1. Two commits that do not share the same parents (have completely different history)
2. Those two commits have the exact same tree sha id (and thus reference the same object files)
3. Pushing both commits results in transferring all the objects in the same tree twice. Although I expect either that Git detects that the tree in the second commit is already present OR that file objects within that tree are already on the server.

---

## Answer (I can't answer anymore, since someone marked this as duplicate).

The solution is unfortunately not that simple.

Every time Git wants to sync two repositories it builds a pack file, that contains all objects necessary (like files, commits, trees). When you execute a `git push`, the remote sends all existing references (branches) and its head commit SHA to the client. This is the problem: The [pack protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt) is not meant to be used per-object, but per-commit.
So, according to the protocol itself, the explained behaviour above is correct. To work around that, I built a simple script every one can use to do a `git push` based on objects, instead of commits.

You find it here: https://github.com/marcj/git-objects-sync

What it does:

1. Takes one commit (only one, you need to execute it on every unsynced parent commit as well) and builds a list of object SHAs (files, trees, commits) that belong to that commit (except parent commit).
2. Sends this list to the server, servers answers back SHAs of objects it does not have yet
3. Client builds a pack file based on the missing object SHAs and sends it to the server with the information which ref needs to be updated to which commit.
4. Server receives pack file, unpacks it and updates the ref with given commit SHA.

Of course this has some drawbacks, but I described them in the linked Github repository.

With my script above you get now following:

```
marc@osx ~/git-test (branch11*) $ # added new branch11 as explained at the very top
marc@osx ~/git-test (branch11*) $ python git-sync.py refs/heads/branch11
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 158 bytes | 158.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
marc@osx ~/git-test (branch11*) $ git push origin branch11
Everything up-to-date
```

So as you see, it only syncs one object (the commit object), and not the `dummy` file and its tree object again.

Comment: I think the real question here is why are you committing the same thing to multiple branches? I can't wrap my head around why you would do that

Comment: Also your explanation of your process doesn't make sense. What are you branching from in step 4? If it's off of the head of the branch you previously pushed, what you're saying should be impossible. Please be more clear in your example

Comment: @JoePhillips he is not branching `--orphan`, no no wonder this file is not in git :D The question is why does he need this flag

Comment: Possible use-case: I have two completely different branches, but some common files are shared within those two. When I push one branch, I don't want to upload the common files again when I push the second branch. Also, Git detects files by its sha, so it should be able to detect that some files in the tree of the commit are already present on the server.

Comment: I don't see this use case. 1)if 2 branches are completely different, doesn't that mean you should have two repositories? 2) git is not made for storing binary files etc. But if it is really some source code large file you could see at [LFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/manage-large-files)

Comment: It's not about storing binary files, that was just to illustrate and debug easily (as you can see that 10MB are transferred again and again). I don't want to have two separate repositories. The question is more related to Git internals, why and what causes this behaviour, not how valid that use case is.

Comment: My only guess is that the server doesn't trust client to tell it the hash of the file so it must see it for itself by having you upload it

Comment: Well, the server trusts the client. That's the point about calculating the delta and it works fine when the second commit is descendant of the first commit. However, when the second commit is not descendant of the first, it won't calculate the delta correctly. It seems to me, it completely ignores the tree objects from the first commit, when pushing the not-related second commit.

Comment: This is a dup of [Could Git Smart API thin pack calculation ever consider reusing common sub-trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149185/could-git-smart-api-thin-pack-calculation-ever-consider-reusing-common-sub-trees): you've got an extremely low-frequency corner case and avoiding the downside here would mean paying measurable, noticeable overhead every. single. fetch.  It's a bad trade.

Comment: @jthill. thanks, that's (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37262335/979328) the correct answer. Do you want to create an actual answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Nah, no need, when you take the bounty off this we can close it as a dup.

Comment: This sounds like workflow problems and possible misuse of branches. Could you clarify what you mean when you say that you create a branch for each new "experiment"? What is the end-state of a "successful" experiment? Does it get merged somewhere?

Where I'm going with this is that Git isn't optimized as a file management system, its optimized to track and share changes to files - hence when you use --orphan to split projects, your ditching the very thing that makes git useful. It's history.

Comment: @eddiemoya It don't use branches, I uses plain references. A experiment has a lot of commits in it, so I use a lot the history feature of Git.

Comment: How often do you create a new experiment? Are we talking multiple times a day or a couple times a week?

Comment: Many, like dozens or hundreds a day, but not more than a few hundreds in total, maybe 1-2 thousands per repository (I delete older/unused ones).

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt Sorry but that sounds a bit contradictory so im a little confused. From the explanation above you are clearly using orphaned branches for each experiment. I think the root of your problem is the use of --orphan. You seem to be using branches, but not taking advantage of the benefits of branching properly. The solution is probably some combination of changing your use of branches and/or modifying your file structure to take advantage of branch history.

Could you please answer my other questions from above? I'm gonna ask some additional questions in a new comment below.

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt I think I can propose a solution for you if you can give me a few things. 1. The lifecycle of an experiment. 1a. Do they ever get merged into the main branch?  1b. Are they ever permanent/ perpetual/long-lived, or do they all eventually get deleted? 2. The lifecycle of one of the common files (the ones that are used in multiple experiments). 2a - Are shared files often the same set of shared files, or is it arbitrary? 2b - Are you able to structure your files freely, can you nest them in folders as you see fit (this will matter for my possible solution).

Comment: @eddiemoya, no I don't use branches, only references. To your questions.
1a. lifecircle can be 1min or months. 1b. some are permanent, 2. Same as 2a. often the same files since often I only change one line of code between experiments, 2b. yeah probably yet

Comment: "Could you clarify what you mean when you say that you create a branch for each new "experiment"?"
I create a git tree with all my files, and use "git commit-tree" to create a commit without parent (root commit) in no branch. Create a ref pointing to that commit then. Those refs never get merged, I just use it as file storage. Often I add additional commits to that root commit, like when experiments ends and I add some results to it.
The advantage about that is don't "git clone" doesn't pull all refs automatically.

I often use git diff ref1...ref2 to see changes made between experiments.

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt Sorry but I have more questions. I don't want to give you a solution that makes no sense. Regarding: "often I only change one line of code between experiments" - does this mean that your common/shared files are often not actually identical? Where I'm going here, is that I think you are using "references" (as you keep insisting, branches are also references btw) as if they were folders to split up varying instances of a core project. Is that more or less right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163341/discussion-between-eddiemoya-and-marc-j-schmidt).

Comment: By the way, if you have a common baseline set of data, there's no reason not to tag that and use it as the common parent of the experiments using it.  After your `git branch --orphan` you can `git reset --soft baseline` to tell git about the actual structure of your history

Comment: This question is not about the smart http backend.

Comment: @jthill I added the solution. Please remove that duplicate mark.

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt I have reopened the question: you can add your answer below (and accept it).

Answer (score 1):

Git develops its manifests and packs up objects using only an exchange of references. If the branch you are pushing has no common ancestors with the remote, it's going to pack and re-upload all the objects reachable from that branch.

The sequence goes something like this

- You: send list of your current remote refs to remote
- Remote: send all objects not reachable from that list to client and a list of new refs
- You: Add objects to your local database and update remote refs
- You: find all commits on your branch not reachable from any remote ref (No common ancestor, all commits on branch will be sent)
- You: build a manifest out of the diffs for those commits (finds 10mb file)
- You: pack and send to remote

The remote will recognize objects already in its database and use the existing objects.

The logic is that sending a few unnecessary files from time to time is far more efficient than walking the entire history (potentially tens or hundreds of thousands of objects being accessed and compared) on every push.

Comment: Note that Git *could* use have/want exchanges on all objects, rather than just on commits. In this case it would find that the large files already exist (by hash ID), but that would require a lot more data-exchange in the "slow part" of the fetch or push transaction.

Comment: @torekt: That's not true. It's always less data exchange than in the current version. Current version: uploads all sha ids AND its content of _all_ files. Different version: Uploads all sha-ids and returns back which are not on the server already, then sends the content of missing objects only.I don't see how sending all local git sha ids only would require more data-exchange than all sha ids + its actual content.

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt Keep in mind that your use case is not what git is designed to do. Git is optimized for branching, merging, and tracking a single code base over a long period of time. Under normal circumstances, yes, it would require transmitting fewer actual bytes, but the few hundred milliseconds it takes to connect, wait for the server to filter and respond, and build a second manifest would be an order of magnitude longer than just pushing all the data. You have created an edge case where this is not true, but fixing it would degrade the performance of the primary use case.

Comment: @LightBender I disagree. Git is not only optimized for what you said, but also for efficient file storage. The very heart of Git. I want to utilize this and its internal model with commits, tree, file objects, references is perfectly fine for my use-case. The only thing where it isn't perfect when it comes to pushing changes, since Git uses only the direct parent commits history to build the delta pack.

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt You keep insisting that git is optimized for what you want to do, but it's clearly stated purpose isn't file management, and everyone is trying to explain to you that while it maybe good at some aspects of what you want - its not optimized for your use case. Specifically with regard to the file transfers. There have been multiple explanations of ways to squeeze parts of what you want out of git - but your not going to get a perfect solution out of the box. Your going to need to sacrifice workflow or project structure, or something else. Or write your own git plugin to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to stop using `--orphan` to create new experiment branches.

**Workflow**

1. Create your initial project.
2. Add and commit your core/common files to the master branch
3. Create all the non-orphaned branches you want for every experiment. Create them based on the master branch.

That's it.

**What's going on?**

You have insisted that you aren't using branches and that you are only using references. However, [branches are a kind of reference](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References). Moreover, `git checkout --orphan <newthing>` [does actually create a branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---orphanltnewbranchgt). The trouble is that its a branch that doesn't know about anything that was previously added to the repository because it has no parents. It's essentially the same thing as having created a whole new repository.

If you create new branches with `git checkout -b <newthing> master`, then git will not bother uploaded files that were already in master.

**How do you manage new common files now?**

Let's say someday you have a new file which you want all future experiments to make use - of a new shared/common file. All you would need to do is add that file to `master` and create your next experiment branch based on the updated master branch. If want that file to be available to your existing/previously created experiments, you would just need to checkout those branches and run `git pull --rebase origin master`. This would pull in the commits you added to master, which would contain the newly added file(s).

**Mounting Complexity**

When you start doing pulls, things might start getting complicated. There are a couple different strategies for how to update branches, and using `--rebase` is one of those strategies. It's not required, but it's probably the better way to go. There additional things to consider such as how to manage conflicting changes, but those are seemingly outside the scope of this question. There are plenty of resources available to explain rebasing/merging etc.

**TR;DR**

Don't try to manage commit-trees and parent/child relationships manually. Just let `git` do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned; Git will only check for blobs on the branch you are pushing, but you can trick Git to check for blobs in the master branch by including it in your ancestry.

It seems you really want to work on an orphan branch, so you can merge the master branch only when you want to push. You can ignore the whole contents of the master branch by using the `ours` strategy.

```
 % git checkout --orphan branch2
 % git rm -rf .
 % git checkout master dummy
 % git commit -m 'Init on branch2'
 % git merge --strategy=ours --allow-unrelated-histories master -m 'Fake merge'
 % git push origin branch2
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 336 bytes | 336.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
To github.com:felipec/bounty-test.git
 * [new branch]      branch2 -> branch2
```

The contents are exactly the same:

```
 % git rev-parse branch2:
d0f549d94dbba116d782293722cf9b43e8a67819
 % git rev-parse branch2^:
d0f549d94dbba116d782293722cf9b43e8a67819
```

If you don't want to mess with your original branch, you can create a new branch just for pushing.

Also, you can just start off based of master, and just throw away all the files:

```
 % git checkout -b branch3 master
 % git rm -rf .
 % git checkout master dummy
 % git commit -m 'Init on branch3'
 % git push origin branch3
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 236 bytes | 236.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:felipec/bounty-test.git
 * [new branch]      branch3 -> branch3
```

If you really want this rather specific use-case to be handled properly in Git you might want to contact the developers on the [mailing list](http://mailto:git@vger.kernel.org). They might offer you other alternatives, but it's possible that they won't agree there's something that can be improved in the code without significant trade offs for other cases.

*Note*: I don't know why you had to add the dummy file in your steps, on my side the whole contents of the master branch are staged when I do `git checkout --orphan`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) in your scenario. Git LFS is made for managing large files on git repositories.

As per [this github issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/307)  (which has [been resolved](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/680) ~2 years ago), duplicate files are managed as a single entity with the same OID. Thus they are pushes only once and fetched just once.

At least Github and Gitlab already include support for git-lfs in all the repositories.