# Is "git fetch" smart enough to not re-download blobs it already has but on different refs?

Tags: git

Assume the following scenario:

- Repo A has 1,000,000 files and many trees, 1,000 commits and 1 branch
- Repo B has 1,000,000 files with 990,000 of them common with repo A and also a number of trees are the same (but far from all), however its 1,000 commits are all different and so is the branch

You clone repo A on disk, then add a remote to repo B and run `git fetch remoteB`. Even if refs and commits differ, is the Git transfer protocol smart enough to not re-download most of the blobs?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes, it will only download what you are missing.

Comment: As I know, yes as long as the objects are reachable from any existing ref. If an object is unreachable or even dangling, `git fetch` will re-download it.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149185/could-git-smart-api-thin-pack-calculation-ever-consider-reusing-common-sub-trees/37262335#37262335).

Comment: See jthill's link. In theory Git could enumerate every object down to the blob level, but in practice it doesn't. As part of their work on making Git perform better with truly enormous repositories, though, Microsoft have been improving things; perhaps someday it will detect these cases.